# POST changes to OPTIONS + Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: ajax, xml, soap, wsdl, cors

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 500.

I am trying to send a xml soap with ajax but  gives me that error. I have tried many option but nothing seems to work, here is the code:

```
var soapMessage =
                '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://xxx.xxx/">'+
                '<soapenv:Header/>'+
                '<soapenv:Body>'+
                   '<wsdl:test1>'+
                      '<PUI>12345</PUI>'+
                   '</wsdl:test1>'+
               ' </soapenv:Body>'+
             '</soapenv:Envelope>';

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://xxx.xxx', 
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'xml', 
                data: soapMessage, 
                crossDomain: true,
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"',
                headers: {
                    SOAPAction: "http://xxx.xxx"
                },
                success: function (msg, data) {
                    alert(msg);

                },
                error: function (msg, data) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

what am I doing wrong here? I send a POST action but it read it as OPTION.
How to fix this?

I use Boomerang Rest and Soap Client to test this service and it gives me response correctly. When I use my own program as above it gives me XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxxx" error. I am using apache tomcat 6.0 and using a Java web Application for the code

Comment: I see the new information about Boomerang Rest and Soap Client in the update to your question but the possible solutions remain the same as outlined in my answer: If you don’t have access to configure the server you’re sending the requests to, then to get the client-side JavaScript code to work as you want in browsers, your only solutions are to 1) run your own proxy using code from something like https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/ or 2) send your requests to an public open CORS proxy service like the instance at https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ in the form described in my answer.

Comment: As it looks from sideshowbarker's answer the issue is not with the code but with CORS-configuration of the SOAP server. From the example SOAP it looks like you control the server, so change its configuration! This https://enable-cors.org/server.html might be useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re doing that request cross-origin, so the server you’re making the request to must send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to indicate it allows cross-origin requests.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for details.

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and Fetch follow the same-origin policy. So, a web application using XMLHttpRequest or Fetch could only make HTTP requests to its own domain.

And the reason an `OPTIONS` request happens is that when you send a cross-origin request with a `Content-Type` header that has a value other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`, your browser first does a [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) check.

Your request sends `Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"`, so that causes a preflight.

As far as workarounds if the server you’re sending the request to is not one that you control and can configure, you can  use an open reverse proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/.

The way it works is that instead of sending your request directly to `http://xxx.xxx`, you send it instead to https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://xxx.xxx and that proxies your request and responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and other expected CORS headers.

Of course you need to realize that if your request contains any credentials, you’d be exposing those to the maintainers of `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`.

Comment: if I use Boomerang Soap and Rest client it works perfectly, why with my application doesn't work?

Comment: Short answer: Browsers are very different from other clients in this regard. Longer answer: The reason it works in other clients is that they allow your code to make cross-origin requests to any server without restrictions. But web browsers do not—browsers by default do not allow JavaScript running in a web application at one origin to make a cross-origin request to a server at another origin. But they do allow it if the server at the other origin sends back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to indicate the server is opting in to receiving cross-origin requests.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for an overview of what’s happening here.

Comment: hopefully this site never goes down and hopefully you aren't sending any critical data to this site and they start snooping on it... This answer would not be acceptable in almost any non-personal context.

Answer (score 1):

My work around for this was to write a filter that appends the origin as an accepted origin onto any options request and added it to whatever servlet that would need to accept such requests. Here's my implementation:

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    private static List<String> validServers = Arrays.asList([you need to fill this in with whatever sites you want to allow access]);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(origin)) { //this is a cors request
                boolean hasPrefix = origin.contains("/");
                boolean hasPort = origin.contains(":");
                String serverAlias = origin.substring(hasPrefix ? origin.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 : 0, hasPort ? origin.lastIndexOf(":") : origin.length());
                if (validServers.contains(serverAlias)) {
                    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE");
                    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
                    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
                    //credentials are not sent on options requests, kick out here so that the access control headers and nothing else can be returned
                    if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
                        response.setStatus(200);
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    response.sendError(HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                    response.flushBuffer();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```